# How to add SurfaceView displaying camera preview with opacity

Tags: android, surfaceview

I want to add SurfaceView which displaying camera preview to my layout. It should be semi-transparent (alpha 0.5). I add View by addView() method.
Ho to do that. I tried animation but it seems to not works with camera.

My Surfave view looks like that:

```
public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

   private SurfaceHolder holdMe;
   private Camera theCamera;

   public ShowCamera(Context context,Camera camera) {
      super(context);
      theCamera = camera;
      holdMe = getHolder();
      holdMe.addCallback(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      try   {
         theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
         theCamera.startPreview(); 
      } catch (IOException e) {
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
   }

}
```

My minAPI = 8.